# How to robustly handle spotty connectivity over TCP sockets?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tcp, tcpsocket

I'm building a client that talks to a remote server via a TCP socket. Occasionally, the client will pass a message to the server, or the server will pass a message to the client.

This will run on laptops, so connectivity is going to be pretty spotty. They might lose their wifi, they might put the laptop to sleep and wake it at a later point, etc. I'm implementing a ping-pong system to detect loss of connection (all on the same socket. client pings, server pongs).

**What should I do when a ping fails?** (or the client sends a message that is never acknowledged) I can either:

1. Keep pinging until I get a ping back
2. Close the socket and repeatedly attempt to connect the socket until the connection succeeds

Option 1 is obviously a little simpler, but I don't know if it will get me the behavior that I want. What happens if the server has closed its side of the connection? Also, if, say, the laptop just doesn't have a wifi connection, will all those pings just get queued up and then be sent all together once it does get wifi back? Not sure I want to hammer my server with thousands of pings every time someone reconnects.

Client is written in Flash, so not a lot of low-level access to options like KEEP_ALIVE.

Comment: Why can't you ping the socket itself with your own specified ping packet. if that fails 3 times or > 5-10 seconds consider the socket dead, close it from both sides and initiate a new one?

Comment: Err, you would need to set server timeout at say 20 seconds and client at 10 while refreshing that socket constantly.

Comment: Yeah, it's already my own custom "ping".

Comment: I guess your question is answered then, make the timeout on client side 10 seconds and on server 20 seconds and then open new sockets if something happened to the old one.